# How to convert TextStyle from Jetpack Compose to android.graphics.Typeface?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-typeface

I need to draw text onto `Canvas` in Compose, for this purpose I need a `TextPaint` with `android.graphics.Typeface`.

Is there a way to easily convert Compose `TextStyle` to a `android.graphics.Typeface`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can resolve `android.graphics.Typeface` object from a `androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle` object using `LocalFontFamilyResolver`.

```
val style: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
val resolver: FontFamily.Resolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current

val typeface: Typeface = remember(resolver, style) {
    resolver.resolve(
        fontFamily = style.fontFamily,
        fontWeight = style.fontWeight ?: FontWeight.Normal,
        fontStyle = style.fontStyle ?: FontStyle.Normal,
        fontSynthesis = style.fontSynthesis ?: FontSynthesis.All,
    )
}.value as Typeface
```

Comment: Oof, that looks really promising!

Comment: If setting this Typeface on a TextView, consider also applying the TextStyle's lineHeight and letterSpacing properties onto the TextView as well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only workaround that i found is to provide with resources:

```
val textTypeface: android.graphics.Typeface? =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) LocalContext.current.resources.getFont(R.font.quicksand_light) else null
```

However if android version < android oreo, idk how to provide the font, so i fallback to default fount.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, this is not converting `TextStyle` (which internally holds information about the `font`).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    val textPaint = TextPaint()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        textPaint.apply {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "fonts/yourfont.ttf")
                ...
        }
        drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText("test", yourStart, yourEnd, X, Y, textPaint)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately, this is not answering the question - providing a way of converting `TextStyle` to `Typeface`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you: Wanting to draw text to a Canvas in a TextStyle that is defined in my Compose Theme.

I found out you can use `androidx.compose.ui.text.Paragraph.paint(canvas)` to draw text to the `Canvas`.

That in itself has no way to set offsets for the paint job, so you can use `drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.withTranslation()` to move the drawing to a specified offset.

```
val paragraph = Paragraph(
  text = "Hello",
  style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
  constraints = Constraints(),
  density = LocalDensity.current,
  fontFamilyResolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current,
)
val colorOnSurface = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface

Canvas(
  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
  //
  drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.withTranslation(
    100f,
    100f
  ) {
      paragraph.paint(
        canvas = drawContext.canvas,
        color = colorOnSurface,
      )
  }
}
```

This seems quite sketchy, but it's the best I've got ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score -1):

To draw text to canvas, you can do like this

```
@Composable
fun DrawText() {
    val paint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint()
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        paint.apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            textSize = 24f
            typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD) // your typeface

            //other methods like color, dither, fontMetrics, shadow etc...are also available 

        }

        drawIntoCanvas {
            it.nativeCanvas.drawText("Hello World", size.width/2, size.height/2, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

I think to convert `TextStyle`(compose library) to `typeface` will be a pain since no support from android, If you want to draw text to canvas I think this will be enough

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately, this is not answering the question. I know how to draw text on canvas, I'm looking for a way of converting `TextStyle` to `Typeface`.