# Compose Text - width in chars

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Is there a way to tell a `Text` composable to be as wide as e.g. 2 characters no matter what the provided text is?

I want to have a row with weights and some fixed size cells but I do want the fixed size cells to have a width that's exactly as large as it needs to be to contain n characters of the provided font...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TextMeasurer` to measure a text and set a width according the first 2 characters (or with a fixed text with 2 characters).

Something like:

```
val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult =
    textMeasurer.measure(
        text = AnnotatedString(text.substring(0,2)), //you have to check if the length is <2
        style = LocalTextStyle.current
    )
val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
val density = LocalDensity.current

Text(
    text = text,
    modifier = Modifier
       .width( with(density){textSize.width.toDp()} )
       .background(Yellow), //it is not needed
    maxLines = 1
)
```

Comment: That's my idea as well but in xml there was something like `ems`. With your suggestion I must know what the widest character in the current font is - otherwise the calculation is not accurate or I must add some buffer...

Answer (score 0):

TextMeasurer.measure() does measure the width occupied by a string, but is much less efficient the using the Paint.measureText() method. JetPack Compose, unfortunately, no  longer uses the Typeface model used by Paint: you need a conversion: see [How to convert TextStyle from Jetpack Compose to android.graphics.Typeface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800896)

```
    val resolver: FontFamily.Resolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
    val typeface: Typeface = remember(resolver, textStyle) {
        resolver.resolve(
            fontFamily = textStyle.fontFamily,
            fontWeight = textStyle.fontWeight ?: FontWeight.Normal,
            fontStyle = textStyle.fontStyle ?: FontStyle.Normal,
            fontSynthesis = textStyle.fontSynthesis ?: FontSynthesis.All,
        )
    }.value as Typeface
    paint.typeface = typeface
    paint.textSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { textStyle.fontSize.toPx()}
    // Paint letter spacing is in ems which are multiples of the textSize/fontSize but letter spacings in TextStyle are in sp.
    paint.letterSpacing = (textStyle.letterSpacing.value ?: 0f) / textStyle.fontSize.value

    width = paint.measureText ("text")
```

This might seem rather cumbersome but the conversion can wrapped into a function to be called once only for each TextStyle. The text measurement is very much faster than the Compose version

For 1000 random 2 character strings Paint: 14 ms, textMeasurer 2s
For 1000 random 10 character strings Paint: 65 ms, textMeasurer 3s 
For 1000 random 100 character strings Paint: 300 ms, textMeasurer 5s 
On a Blackview 60

Note that TextMeasurer gives results that are consistently 1 pixel wider than Paint.measureText(), and even wider than Paint.getTextBounds()